# Select Values From SP And Temporary Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a Stored Procedure in MSSQL 2008, inside of this i've created a Temporary Table, and then i executed several inserts into the temporary Table. 
How can i select all the columns of the Temporary Table outside the stored procedure? I Mean, i have this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[LIST_CLIENTS]

    CREATE TABLE #CLIENT(
         --Varchar And Numeric Values goes here
     )

  /*Several Select's and Insert's against the Temporary Table*/

  SELECT * FROM #CLIENT

END
```

In another Query i'm doing this:

```
sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options', 1 
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO

sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1 
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO

    SELECT * 
    INTO #CLIENT 
    FROM OPENROWSET
    ('SQLOLEDB','Server=(local);Uid=Cnx;pwd=Cnx;database=r8;Trusted_Connection=yes;
    Integrated Security=SSPI',
    'EXEC dbo.LIST_CLIENTS ''20110602'', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL')
```

But i get this error:

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure LIST_CLIENTS, Line 43
Invalid object name '#CLIENT'.
```

I've tried with Global Temporary Tables and It doesn't work.
I know that is the scope of the temporary table, but, how can i get the table outside the scope of the SP?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please tag the question with the version of SQL Server you are using? Also if you are using a trusted connection, why are you passing uid and pwd?

Comment: you do know that global temporary tables are declared with ## ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is something deeper going on here.

One idea is to use a table variable inside the stored procedure instead of a #temp table (I have to assume you're using SQL Server 2005+ but it's always nice to state this up front). And use OPENQUERY instead of OPENROWSET. This works fine for me:

```
USE tempdb;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.proc_x
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @x TABLE(id INT);
    INSERT @x VALUES(1),(2);
    SELECT * FROM @x;
END
GO

SELECT *
  INTO #client 
  FROM OPENQUERY
  (
    [loopback linked server name], 
    'EXEC tempdb.dbo.proc_x'
  ) AS y;

SELECT * FROM #client;

DROP TABLE #client;

DROP PROCEDURE dbo.proc_x;
```

Another idea is that perhaps the error is occurring even without using `SELECT INTO`. Does the stored procedure reference the `#CLIENT` table in any dynamic SQL, for example? Does it work when you call it on its own or when you just say `SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET` instead of `SELECT INTO`? Obviously, if you are working with the #temp table in dynamic SQL you're going to have the same kind of scope issue working with a @table variable in dynamic SQL.

At the very least, name your outer #temp table something other than `#CLIENT` to avoid confusion - then at least nobody has to guess which #temp table is not being referenced correctly.

Comment: Yes, it worked! But, i have another question, i don't understand the difference between OPENQUERY and OPENROWSET Functions, Both instructions retrieves rows from a Query. Sorry for the 'Noob' question, but, i'm really bad with SQL.

Comment: The only real difference I know of is that `OPENQUERY` requires that a linked server exists, and `OPENROWSET` requires that you specify all of the other connection parameters. Docs are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Since the global temp table failed, use a real table, run this when you start your create script and drop the temp table once you are done to make sure.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.temptable', 'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN 
DROP TABLE dbo.temptable
END

CREATE TABLE dbo.temptable 
(    ... )
```

Comment: @AaronBertrand thanks, i missed that. Changed my answer. Was confusing since Op only used 1 # in his example.

Comment: Well, this kills concurrency... what happens if two users run the procedure at the same time? You'd need to use sp_getapplock or some other semaphore mechanism to make sure that the entire process was protected... this can obviously get tricky when using loopback linked servers and therefore, possibly, distributed transactions...

Comment: @AaronBertrand You are right again, I guess he should make a permanent table with each user having his own rows in it (include userid in the table), and then delete those rows once he is done and once he starts the procedure that would have created the table.

Comment: I suspect the answer is simpler than that - a @table variable, for example, may avoid the issue altogether. Still experimenting, cannot reproduce the issue yet.

Comment: @AaronBertrand let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2033/discussion-between-t-clausen-dk-and-aaron-bertrand)

Comment: @AaronBertrand In this query there will be concurrency. I don't know to use the SP that you mention, but, i'll search about it. In this moment, it's the only way that i see, because this is a heavy query and the concurrency is a very important part in the execution.

Thank you

Comment: @Astantler please see my revised answer. Switch to OPENQUERY / @ client instead of OPENROWSET / # client inside the proc. Or just define #client outside of the procedure when you call it, then you don't need select into or openquery/rowset.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the two queries within the same connection and use a global temp table.

Comment: Yes, a global temp table always *sounds* like a good idea. Until two users call the stored procedure at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2008 you can declare [User-Defined Table Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522526%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) which represent the definition of a table structure. Once created you can create table parameters within your procs and pass them a long and be able to access the table in other procs.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason for such behavior is that when you call OPENROWSET from another server it firstly and separately requests the information about procedure output structure (METADATA). And the most interesting thing is that this output structure is taken from the first SELECT statement found in the procedure. Moreover, if the SELECT statement follows the IF-condition the METADATA request ignores this IF-condition, because there is no need to run the whole procedure - the first met SELECT statement is enough. (By the way, to switch off that behavior, you can include SET FMTONLY OFF in the beginning of your procedure, but this might increase the procedure execution time).

The conclusions:

— when the METADATA is being requested from a temp table (created in a procedure) it does not actually exists, because the METADATA request does not actually run the procedure and create the temp table.

— if a temp table can be replaced with a table variable it solves the problem

— if it is vital for the business to use temp table, the METADATA request can be fed with fake *first* SELECT statement, like:

```
declare @t table(ID int, Name varchar(15));
if (0 = 1) select ID, Name from @t;         -- fake SELECT statement
create table #T (ID int, Name varchar(15));
select ID, Name from #T;                    -- real SELECT statement
```

— and one more thing is to use a common trick with FMTONLY (that is not my idea) :

```
declare @fmtonlyOn bit = 0;
if 1 = 0 set @fmtonlyOn = 1;
set fmtonly off;
create table #T (ID int, Name varchar(15));      
if @fmtonlyOn = 1 set fmtonly on;
select ID, Name from #T;
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting the error is because the temp table #Client was not declared before you ran the procedure to insert into it. If you declare the table, then execute the list proc and use direct insert -

INSERT INTO #Client

EXEC LIST_CLIENTS